# Replace a random block of characters in a string in R

Tags: regex, r, replace

I have a text and I want to replace a text block in a line, like that:

> "\t\t\tFGHGFJKJKJKGDSJS"

with

> x= "ABCCCBBHHJJJH"

I'm interested in changing just the text block (FGHGFJKJKJKGDSJS) without modyfing the presence of other special characters. So obtaining:

> "\t\t\tABCCCBBHHJJJH"

Do it exist a way to replace FGHGFJKJKJKGDSJS without clearly specify the exact combination of letters?

I found a solution in this way: txt[n° of the line] = paste0(\t,\t,\t,x)

But I would like to know whether there is a more general solution.

Comment: Please provide a several examples of starting string and resulting string after the replace so we can more clearly understand what you want.

Comment: We need to know whats after "\t\t\tFGHGFJKJKJKGDSJS" or a full example of your string. You first need to catch the string and then replace it. Also the number of the characters is always the same? Or the characters are always the same?

Comment: Thanks to everybody. First of all, I know that I have to specify the line of the text, but now I' m providing a simple example. Then, I want just replace whichever text block (and only that) present in this line, keeping the presence of the three tabs (\t\t\t).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> library(stringr)
> mystring <- "\t\t\tFGHGFJKJKJKGDSJS"
> x <- "ABCCCBBHHJJJH"
> str_replace(mystring,"\\w+",x)
[1] "\t\t\tABCCCBBHHJJJH"
```

`\w+`mean match any character or number or underscore at least once and as many as possible. So each part not a normal char will be replace by your `x` variable.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. But if for example within the block text there is a special character, the replacing works with just the text before the special characters e.g. mystring <- "\t\t\tFGHGFJKJKJKGD-SJS", and I obtain "\t\t\tABCCCBBHHJJJH-SJS. While I want to replace everything after \t\t\t.

Comment: @CafféSospeso write your exact requirements, which chars at start of line do you wish to keep ? If you're searching to keep blank chars (whitespace, tab, etc.) this one: `str_replace(mystring,"\\S+",x)` should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
> a = "\t\t\tDFGGD"
> gsub("(\t\t\t).*","\\1ABCDF",a)
[1] "\t\t\tABCDF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring <- "\t\t\tFGHGFJKJKJKGDSJS"
x <- "ABCCCBBHHJJJH"    
sub('\\w+',x,mystring,ignore.case=T)
```